# JMeter TCPSampler - how to handle a custom protocol with a periodic keep alive?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I am relatively new to JMeter however I have been doing Performance testing for almost a decade.

I am working with a proprietary TCP protocol that sends a keep alive periodically - through the existing TCP connection.

I am struggling to understand how I can fork the JMeter 'thread group' to handle a TCP Keep alive received over the same TCP session.

Any ideas?

Thank you brainstrust!

edit: I'm using the TCPsampler and have read the help page. I'll try to provide some more detail shortly about what's happening and how the protocol is written.

edit2: Unfortunately because it's a propriety protocol I cannot reveal the exact nature of the protocol itself but it's largely irrelevant to the problem I'm facing.

Basically, I use the 1st TCP sampler to 'start/authenticate' the session with the server. This is configured the following options: 
 1. TCPClient classname: LengthPrefixedBinaryTCPClientImpl (my protocol is implemented this standard way)
 2. Re-use connection ON.
 3. Close connection OFF.
 4. Set NoDelay OFF.
 5. SO_Linger: nothing
 6. Text to send: my hex code for the protocol (this is correct)

I get the response from the first TCP request and then I want to start interacting, however in the session, the server sends a keep alive mid-stream, so occassionally when I send a request, I get an unexpected keep alive response instead (it's an open stream of data).

This is what I would like to solve.

I attempted to use a recursive test fragment, so that on KeepAlive response, it would send the request again however one cannot recurse the test fragments (it throws a Java error on Run attempt).

I hope this gives more context! Thank you for your patience (I'm a newbie SO user!)

Comment: Do you use WebSockets?

Comment: I'm not sure what that is. I am using the default TCPsampler.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below options if it helps with you sceario:-

> If "**Re-use connection**" is selected, connections are shared between
>   Samplers in the same thread, provided **that the exact same host name
>   string and port are used**. Different hosts/port combinations will use
>   different connections, as will different threads. If both of "**Re-use
>   connection**" and "**Close connection**" are selected, the socket will be
>   closed after running the sampler. On the next sampler, another socket
>   will be created. You may want to close a socket at the end of each
>   thread loop.
>
> If an error is detected - or "**Re-use connection**" is not selected - the
>   socket is closed. Another socket will be reopened on the next sample.
>
> The following properties can be used to control its operation: 
>   tcp.status.prefix text that precedes a status numbertcp.status.suffix
>   text that follows a status numbertcp.status.properties name of
>   property file to convert status codes to messagestcp.handler Name of
>   TCP Handler class (default TCPClientImpl) - only used if not specified
>   on the GUI

For more details:-https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#TCP_Sampler

Comment: Hi Sunny, thanks again for your assistance. I am currently using this "re-use connection" in my configured TCPSampler. I will be able to provide some more detail of the problem shortly. Unfortunately because it's a propriety protocol I cannot reveal the exact nature of the protocol itself but it's largely irrelevant to the problem I'm facing.